# How can I convert my hash map to a method

Tags: java, methods

I have this map to convert strings to iso2 code

This is the code

```
Map<String, String> countries = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (String iso : Locale.getISOCountries()) {
            Locale l = new Locale("", iso);
            countries.put(l.getDisplayCountry(), iso);
```

**How I use it**

```
countries.get("France")
```

But I want it to be as a method then I'll have `method("France")` and then it does the job.

Comment: You want it to be a method of what? And why do you want to do such a thing?

Comment: Like a method that I call it only when I need it, and also makes my code a bit tidy. I'm looking for a method to cover all the process of map. As I said then I can call it by `method("France")`

Comment: @user3026034 could you explain what's wrong with the methods proposed so far?

Answer (score 0):

How come you don't know how to write methods? Decided to skip the tutorials?

```
public String myMethod(String country) {
    return countries.get(country);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
String method(String country)
{
    return countries.get(country);
}
```